# What could be happening in this mixed effect model fitting process?

Tags: mixed-model, maximum-likelihood, lme4-nlme, optimization, glmm

When I fit the mixed effect model I got this warning:

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt\$par, ctrl = control\$checkConv,  :
>     Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00202181 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
>
> 2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt\$par, ctrl = control\$checkConv,  :
>     Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
>    - Rescale variables?

I think it is telling me the optimization does not converge, (gradient is not close zero). So I listed more details about the optimization.

[image]

Could any one tell me why we have a large number in Hessian matrix? what is happening there?

Comment: Have you rescaled the variables?

Comment: I second @JimB in rescaling the values. `lme4` hates it when your variables are on very different scales. Sometimes REML can get hung up in the parameter space and not converge, too. I might try using `brms` to run a Bayesian model (needs a C++ compiler, but has very similar API to `lme4`). Give it sensible priors, and they should nudge the algorithm to find a best solution in the parameter space.

Comment: @MarkWhite and JimB thanks for the comments. I scaled, and it DID converge. But I just want to know what happened on non converge case: why large values in Hessian is a bad thing? Numerical issues with IEEE754?

Comment: it's a good question; I wonder myself. It was one of those things that people hand-waved over whenever I was taught multilevel modeling. I'm afraid I don't know enough calculus to understand the Hessian matrix terribly well...

Comment: My assumption (not based on any specific programming of such routines) that efficient double-precision calculations just aren't sufficient when the scales of the variable vary wildly.  If one had better than double-precision arithmetic, then the problem would occur less frequently but certainly wouldn't go away.  (And such calculations would take longer, too.)

Comment: If you're training some kind of logistic regression, then the large hessian could be the result of a large feature pushing you really close to to 0 or 1, which can blow up your loss function's derivatives.